# Youtube Login Redirect Loop

Tags: java, youtube, single-sign-on, google-admin-sdk

We are using Google's **Single-Sign-On** service to login to our corporate account. I can login to the **You tube** account successfully but issue occurs when I try to delete you tube channel which is linked with my Google+ account. Once I clicked on "**Delete Channel**" button You tube redirects me to the login page. Our Single Sign On application authenticates my credentials & redirects me to the Assertion Consumer Service URL but YouTube again redirects me to the login page. Please check out below Relay State parameter which we submit to the Google while login to the You Tube account.

**RelayState** : [https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26next%3D%252F%26hl%3Den&hl=en&service=youtube](http://RelayState%20:%20https://accounts.google.com/CheckCookie?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26app%3Ddesktop%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26next%3D%252F%26hl%3Den&hl=en&service=youtube)

I have referred [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/CzKNtK9rUk0) link

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show some code. Are you handling the cookies correctly?